# Calculation of days and date in DataFrame in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, aggregation

I have DataFrame like below:

```py
rng = pd.date_range('2020-12-01', periods=5, freq='D')
df = pd.DataFrame({"ID" : ["1", "2", "1", "1", "2"],
    "Date" : rng, 
    "status" : ["accepted", "accepted", "not_accepted", "accepted", "not_accepted"]}
)
```

And I need to create DataFrame which will show status of last proposition accepted or not accepted for each ID. To be more precision below I upload result wich I need:

[image]

Comment: Use `df.drop_duplicates('ID', keep='last')`

Comment: `df = df.drop_duplicates('ID', keep='last')`